# no actualiza los campos de mi base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

> tengo el siguiente problema, al momento de actualizar algunos capos
>   de mi tabla me aparece un mensaje de actualizado pero al momento de
>   revisarlo no se actualiza, cual puede ser el error? dejo el código, para saber saber cual puede ser la causa**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> update

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_UpdateprocesoPGG(IN comentario varchar(200),IN codigo varchar(100),IN idproceso int,IN idcourier int,IN idpedido int)
BEGIN 

    UPDATE cotizacion
    SET comentario_envio = comentario , codigo_envio = codigo , id_proceso = idproceso , id_courier = idcourier            
    WHERE  id_cotizacion = idpedido; 

END
//DELIMITER
```

> PHP

```
<?php 
sleep(1);
/*Recibir variables del ajax por POST*/
$proceso           = $_POST['proceso'];
$courier           = $_POST['courier'];
$comentario        = $_POST['comentario'];
$seguimiento       = $_POST['seguimiento'];
$id_pedido         = $_POST['id_pedido'];

?>
<pre><?php var_dump($_POST); ?></pre>
<?php

        include('../configuracion/inicio_conexion.php');


                $result =   $sql="CALL SP_UpdateprocesoPGG('".$comentario."','".$seguimiento."',$proceso,$courier,$id_pedido);";

     if (!$result) {
                 die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
                }

    echo "Success";

                var_dump($result);

        echo'<div class="alert alert-success">
                Registro se actualizo con <strong>Exito!</strong>.
            </div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

- No estás ejecutando nada, solo asignas valores de texto a variables
  pero no se llega a ejecutar lo almacenado en `$sql`. Faltaría algo como
  [`mysqli_query($sql)`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)
- No estas obteniendo correctamente las variables que llegan por POST, los nombres no coinciden.
- Tienes un baile de nombres entre: idpedido, id_pedido e id_cotización que resulta imposible saber donde debería ir cada uno.

*Grosso modo* el código debería ser algo como esto:

```
<?php
sleep(1);
/*Recibir variables del ajax por POST*/
$proceso     = $_POST['proceso'];
$courier     = $_POST['courier'];
$comentario  = $_POST['comentario'];
$seguimiento = $_POST['seguimiento'];
$id_pedido   = $_POST['id_pedido'];

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';

include('../configuracion/inicio_conexion.php');

$sql = "CALL SP_UpdateprocesoPGG('$comentario','$seguimiento',$proceso,$courier,$id_pedido)";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}


var_dump($result);

echo '<div class="alert alert-success">
       Registro se actualizo con <strong>Exito!</strong>.
      </div>
     ';
```

> Simplifique las comillas dobles y simples del SQL porque no hace falta
>   concatenar (al usar dobles) y así queda mucho más sencillo.